# How do I find User Preferences in 2.8?

Tags: installation

The manual for V. 2.80 says: 
 "To open the User Preferences editor go To File ‣ User Preferences. "

User Preference does not exist under File. 
I want to make paths to folders with filepaths
Where do I find it?

Answer (score 6):

User preferences for 2.8 are now under the *Edit > Preferences* menu, to the right of *File* menu.

[image]

Saving and loading of settings has been moved into the *Preferences* window and is now done from a dedicated popup dialog, at the bottom left of the panel.

[image]

Autosave is on by default, meaning that any changes should be saved automatically on (gracious) exit. If *Auto Save* is disabled, a save button is made visible and settings are only saved at user discretion (good for testing with keymaps and other hard to reverse or critical settings).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Blender/I cannot find the window from the manual showing the path of the named Dir.
Ex.
File Pats:
Fonts
Texture
Render output
Etc.
-
There is nothing called User Preference
This is the first time I use this program so I am completely on the bare bottom.

Comment: The official manual is for the current official release 2.79 version, you are probably using 2.8 nightly builds which is in Beta and not out yet

Comment: Should I go back to the 2.79 version?
Or is there a way to make paths to dir with "Temp" files, Rander cache and Render output etc.

Comment: 2.8 is not ready for production yet, If you are using Blender for work you should go for 2.79, otherwise most old settings should still be available there

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is this still the case?  Appears to have moved back to edit menu.

Comment: I think I read somewhere it was moved back yes.I don't currently have an updated build to check it, but will update when I do